# Underscore templating error with backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

When this html code with Backbonejs is opened Chrome Java script console is throwing the following error -  `uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`  , 
but when i remove this one line of code containing usage of `underscore` templating `this.template = _.template($('#listing').html())`
from the `List_view's` `initialize` method its working fine . Why is the usage of underscore templating throwing the error ?? 
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example Backbone Whisky APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="LIB/json2.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>  
    <script type = "text/template" id="listing">
      <li>%= value %</li>
    </script>
    <script>

      Whisky = Backbone.Model.extend();
        firstWhisky = new Whisky({
        name : 'Blenders Pride'
      });
      Whiskies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        Model:Whisky ,
        url:"#"
      });


      first_view = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : 'body',
        initialize : function() { 
          this.$el.empty();
          this.render();
        } , 


        render : function() { 
          this.$el.append("<h1>The Whisky APP</h1>");
         this.list_view = new List_view();
          this.$el.append(this.list_view.render().el);
          return this ; 
        }
      });
      List_view = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        tagName : 'ul' , 
        initialize : function() { 
          this.template = _.template($('#listing').html());
        } , 
        render : function() {
          this.$el.empty();
          this.$el.append("<li>Royal stag</li>");
          this.$el.append("<li>Signature </li> ");
          return this ; 
        }
      });
      index_view = new first_view();    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `$("#listing").html()` is returning `undefined` as the element isn't available yet. You'd need to wait for the DOM to have loaded to access the element by ID. You could confirm this by doing a simple [alert](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/YYvKU/) inline. You need to delay the retrieval until the DOM is ready.

In this case, it's because you've got the script tags in the body, making them unavailable at the time that you've requested them. Move the script tags (and templates), and it will work:

http://jsbin.com/obahux/2/

One issue you'll have is that your syntax is wrong, you should be using `<%` and `%>` for executing code or emitting values:

```
<script type = "text/template" id="listing">
    <li><%= value %></li>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...Its working fine now ..You were right ... Thanks a lot for your time spent in helping me out ..

Answer (score 0):

That's because, in your first_view initialize function you're clearing el with this.$el.empty() that makes body empty and there is nothing in there, all scripts and templates in there will be ommited.

You can find a better solution for clearing it. or just wrap that in another div tag

Comment: Even when the line `this.$el.empty()` is taken out it didnt work , but the first suggested answer for this post worked out well....Thank you for your time spent in trying to help me out ..